# c++ hex string to int in while loop

Tags: c++

Hi I have a part in code as --

```
suppose len = 000000088805C24307142C690000000B6274626D6131333230736D0000000D322E31332E31302D313530333400000004000000E6  

  string len, remainder;  
  int numLen;
  stringstream stream;
  while(remainder!="NULL")  
  {  
     len  = trim(remainder.substr(0,8), '0');  
     if(len.empty())  
        len = "0";  
     stream << len;  
     stream >> hex >> numLen; //problem in this part  
     numLen = (numLen*2);  
     TS << "DATA     : 0x" << remainder.substr(0,8) << " " << remainder.substr(8,numLen) << endt;  
     remainder = remainder.substr(8+numLen);  
  }
```

desired output--

```
DATA     : 00000008 8805C24307142C69  
DATA     : 0000000B 6274626D6131333230736D  
DATA     : 0000000D 322E31332E31302D3135303334  
DATA     : 00000004 000000E6
```

**note--**

len is in hexadecimal, I'm converting it into dec and storing in numLen

while calculating `len` everything is good in the first loop but from the second loop, the value for `numLen` isn't overwritten rather it uses the old value which causes problem.

eg-

```
first loop numLen = 8  
numLen*2 = 16  



second loop numLen = 16 (expected here is 11)  
numLen*2 = 32 (expected here is 22)
```

Please help

Comment: `second loop numLen = 16 (expected here is 11) ` How is 11 expected in the second loop?

Comment: B is hex...dec for it is 11

Comment: Any chance you could actually write a COMPLETE program that does everything - my guess is that your code is doing something wrong outside the code you've posted...

Comment: its just this much... I need to convert a hex value in len into the given desired output...

there are no extra inputs

Comment: So where does `"NULL"` come from? What is `stream`? What type is `len`, what type is `numLen`?

Comment: ohh you mean declarations
sorry here--

   string remainder, len;
   int numLen;
   stringstream stream;

Comment: And exactly what does `trim` do? Although I have copied and pasted your code and written the remainder, I'm not sure it does exactly what is expected...

Comment: trim is function which removes extra 0's... like in remainder.substr(0,8) = 00000008... so len becomes 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, typical case of "should always declare variables at the closes possible scope" - and use error checking!

```
  while(remainder!="NULL")  
  {  
     stringstream stream;
     len  = trim(remainder.substr(0,8), '0');  
     if(len.empty())  
        len = "0";  
     stream << len;  
     stream >> hex >> numLen; //problem in this part  
     numLen = (numLen*2);  
     TS << "DATA     : 0x" << remainder.substr(0,8) << " " << remainder.substr(8,numLen) << endt;  
     remainder = remainder.substr(8+numLen);  
  }
```

Move the `stringstream stream;` into the loop - the problem is that you've read everything in the `stream` the first time around, so the next time, it thinks the string is at the end. When it then tries to read the next data into the `numLen`, it goes wrong, and just doubles the existing value of `numLen`.

Alternatively, use `stream.clear()` somewhere after the `stream >> numLen;`.

Personally, I would move ALL the variables into the loop, and end up with something like this:

```
  while(remainder!="NULL")  
  {  
     std::string len  = trim(remainder.substr(0,8), '0');  
     if(len.empty())  
        len = "0";  
     stringstream stream(len);
     int numLen = 0;
     if (stream >> hex >> numLen)
     {
        numLen = (numLen*2);  
        TS << "DATA     : 0x" << remainder.substr(0,8) << " " << remainder.substr(8,numLen) << endt;  
        remainder = remainder.substr(8+numLen);
     }
     else /* handle error in some way */;
  }
```

By detecting any error, you avoid troubleshooting something that was actually caused by an earlier error.